What are the consequences of a BSP tree without splitting polygons?
I am considering using a BSP to sort my static geometry (sparse vertex count) for transparency.
Usually, you would split a polygon along the plane of the current node and put one half in the front node and the other in the back node.
What are the consequences when I do not split a polygon along the plane and instead put the polygon in both front and back?


What happens when you work through a couple of small non-trivial examples?
